# How can wrap the expression with declare or with clause in psql?

Tags: postgresql, with-statement, declare

Using a psql variable to store a expression in set:

```
\set vix round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2)
```

Call the variable in select :

```
select  :vix as vix from quote 
    where date='2023-12-08'  and :vix is not null 
    order by :vix desc  
    limit 10;
```

It print the output such as below:

```
   vix   
---------
 1466.53
  502.94
  167.57
  163.67
  150.00
  150.00
  141.13
  133.33
  105.58
  100.00
(10 rows)
```

Call the variable `vix` in declare:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE vix float := round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2);
BEGIN
    select  vix as vix from quote 
    where date='2023-12-08'  and vix is not null 
    order by vix desc  
    limit 10;
END $$;
```

It encouter error:

```
ERROR:  column "high" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2)
                          ^
QUERY:  SELECT round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 during statement block local variable initialization
Time: 0.604 ms
```

Put it in with clause:

```
WITH  vix as (
   round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2)
)
select  vix as vix from quote 
where date='2023-12-08'  and vix is not null 
order by vix desc  
limit 10;
```

It encounter error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "round"
LINE 2:    round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2)
```

How can fix them ?

Comment: Variables in pl/pgsql work completely different than variables in the psql client.

Comment: You want `select round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2) as vix from quote`

Comment: Yes,how to set the expression round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2) as an variable in with or do begin structure.

Comment: 1) `high` and `low` are column names from the table `quote` and are unknown to `plpgsql` in the `DECLARE` section. 2) A CTE(WITH) accepts only certain statements per [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH): *Each subquery can be a SELECT, TABLE, VALUES, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.*. This `round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2)` does not qualify as a legitimate statement. 3) I believe what you are looking for in `plpgsql` case is [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a subquery to add a "virtual" column:

```
WITH temp as (
  SELECT *, round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2) AS vix
  FROM quote
)
SELECT *
FROM temp
WHERE date = '2023-12-08'
  AND vix IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY vix DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, round(100*(high/nullif(low,0)-1),2) AS vix
  FROM quote
) AS temp
WHERE date = '2023-12-08'
  AND vix IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY vix DESC
LIMIT 10;
```